# Apple, Banana, Mango, Ananas and Kiwi - Can I reorder the order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

`sort()` orders the elemts alphabetically:

```
var fruits = new Array("Apple", "Banana", "Kiwi", "Ananas", "Mango");
Namen.sort();
document.write(fruits);
```

Well, I don't want the alphabetical order...it should be like

```
var reorderFruits = new Array("Kiwi", "Apple", "Mango", "Banana", "Ananas");
```

Is it possible to reorder the order the way I imagined it? How?

Thank you in advance.
Faili

Edit:

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="apple" checked="checked" />
<label for="apple">Apple</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Banana" checked="checked" />
<label for="Banana">Banana</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Kiwi" />
<label for="Kiwi">Kiwi</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="Mango" checked="checked"/>
<label for="Mango">Mango</label>
```

Well... I get the information from a website I have no access to. No, I want to reorder the order.
In this example it is:

```
Apple -> Banana -> Kiwi -> Mango
```

Now I'm asking whether it is possible to make it to:

```
Kiwi -> Banana -> mango -> Apple
```

Please ask whether there is sth unclear.

Thank you so much.

Comment: don't sort them, then...

Comment: what is the key by which you want to sort them?

Comment: Where are the elements coming from? If they're being populated in some different order, you would need to elaborate on the algorithm that you would use to order them so it could be done programmatically. As provided (K, A, M, B, A) doesn't imply any specific ordering.

Comment: Ah, yes. Well, the sort() was just an example. I was asking whether it is possible to reorder them. I'm writing a GM-Script and can't influence the order instead of creating a function or whatelse with JS.

Comment: What's the sort order in your example? Apple shows up twice, and I can't make any any reasoning to how they're ordered.  Do you just want to randomize them?

Comment: @Lukasz: Well, in this case it's "Kiwi".

Comment: @jmar: var fruits was the first order...I want to "replace" the order of  var fruits by hte order of var reorderFruits.

Comment: @Faili, You need to provide some context I think.  Are there numerous arrays you wish to re-order?  You have to explain how you would re-order them.  If it's just this one, you could just re-declare it with the order you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example that will sort the array by the length of the item.  It will match your desired output on any browser that uses a stable sorting algorithm (which is most of them now).  You can modify the function to sort by any other criteria you want as well.

```
var fruits = new Array("Apple", "Banana","Kiwi",  "Ananas", "Mango");
fruits.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.length - b.length;
});
document.write(fruits);
```

There are some rules with this.  The sort function must compare a and b such that:

- It returns a numeric value indicated whether a is less than, equal to, or greater than b
- Multiple comparisons between the same a and b can happen, and should *always* return the same result for the same a and b.
- Equal values *must* always return 0.

I mention all this because one common (wrong) use for this is to randomize or shuffle an array such the sort function returns a random value.  That will appear to work, but isn't really random and can cause bugs later.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear from your example what sort order you want, but it is possible to [provide your own compare function to the sort() method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/sort), which will allow for arbitrary sort orders.  Here's an example that will do "reverse alphabetical":

```
var fruits = new Array("Apple", "Banana","Kiwi",  "Ananas", "Mango");
fruits.sort(function(x, y) {
  if (x > y) return -1;
  if (x < y) return 1;
  return 0;
});
```

But again, from your example I'm not sure what the compare function should look like in your case.

Comment: I'll get back to you asap.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is. For example you can add them in the order as you like, then the order will be kept. On the other hand if you have them in some order and you want to reorder them as you like then you can change them just like you do with changing values of two variables f.e.

```
var fruits = new string[3] { "Apple", "Banana", "Ananas" };

var tempFruit= fruits[0]; // hold fruit in a temp variable

fruits[0] = fruits[1]; // exchange fruit positions
fruits[1] = tempFruit; // retrieve fruit from position 0 from temp variable
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,

maybe I didn't explain my problem good enough.
Here's the solution that worked out for me.

Thank you though. Without you, I wasn't able to create the following:

```js
var newOrder = ['Kiwi', 'Apple', 'Mango', 'Banana', 'Ananas'];

for (var i = 0; i < newOrder.length - 1; i++) {
    var section = "label[for='" + newOrder[i] + "']";
    var section_2 = "#" + newOrder[i];
    $(section).insertAfter(section_2);
    var section_3 = "#" + newOrder[i + 1];
    $(section_3).insertAfter(section);
}

var section = "label[for='" + newOrder[newOrder.length - 1] + "']";
var section_2 = "#" + newOrder[newOrder.length - 1];
$(section).insertAfter(section_2);
```

Well, I had to use the label-tag. It was necessary to have a correct name after the checkbox. Some checkboxes were checked, others not.

Thank you.